# Home Network Crashes with Git Push

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, git, github, github-desktop

Whenever I run the command git push origin master...my home network locks up as in ONLY git works (it completes the push).

Defining home network locks up:  NOTHING else will work on the network except the actual git push in progress. Try to open a website, server not available. Try to connect to a game, no network connection. A PS3 streaming Netflix will stop streaming.... THE VERY second git completes the push, the entire network is available to everything else again.

I'm using GitHub with their LFS service. I'm on a cable internet connection with over 2MB down and 500KB up. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To put it plainly, your router sucks.

Your router should queue requests between hosts(connections) and service all *roughly* equally. Unless you've setup QoS priority for that PC it shouldnt be devoted 100% bandwidth exclusively.

Rate limiting Git with something like trickle on Linux could resolve it but really I'd be looking for a new router.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem, and my fix was updating the firmware on my router to the latest version (from 2.0.0.4 to 2.0.0.7 on my Linksys E1200). Once I did that, git push no longer broke my wireless router.